# Library for managing paths/URLs

Tags: c++, c, url, path, cd

Is there any library in C or C++ that helps with managing paths or URLs?

Or maybe functions from standard library from one of these languages

**Example:**

Imagine following API:

```
class Path {
  public:
    Path(std::string &path);

    std::string getPath();

    void cd(std::string &path);
}
```

What I need is that this library will handle following cases:

**Example 1**:

```
Path *p = new Path("/level_one/level_two/level_three");

p->cd("..");
```

and now `p->getPath() == "/level_one/level_two";`,

**Example 2**:

```
p->cd("../level_TWO");
```

and now `p->getPath() == "/level_one/level_TWO";`,

**Example 3**:

```
p->cd("/level_ONE");
```

and now `p->getPath() == "/level_one";`.

I hope that these examples made my problem more clear. Basically I need library, that will keep track all *change directory* commands with respect to syntax of *cd* on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Boost Fileystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) library has a path class which supports much of what you're looking for.

Instead of a `cd` command, it overloads `operator=/` for descending directories and has a parent_path() method for ascending.

It's very portable and easy to learn. It is, however, unable to deal (AFAIK) with URL paths.

Comment: Boost isn't an option in my case. But I haven't written this anywhere, so I accept this answer. Also proposed solution has a nice API. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [google-url](http://code.google.com/p/google-url) project, its used inside Chrome and its C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, google-url doesn't compile under Linux. Also its API is to complicated for simple task as managing.